# Swift: override property class

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, swift-protocols

With Swift Protocols, extensions and Constraints, I'm looking to do two things:

1. Create a base-abstract class
2. Subclass and override property.

   ```
   class PropertyBase { }

   class PropA : PropertyBase {}

   class PropB : PropertyBase {}

   class ControllerBase {
       var prop: PropertyBase?
   }

   class ControllerA : ControllerBase{
       override var prop: PropA?
   }
   class ControllerB : ControllerBase{
       override var prop: PropB?
   }
   ```

Error:

> Cannot override mutable property 'prop' of type 'PropertyBase?' with covariant type 'PropA?

Would be great to know how I achieve this with a different approach?

### EDIT

I wanted to add to this question with more clarity for what I want to achieve.

In the example, I am building a protocol that deals with an unknown object type, All I know is that the type could be a `String` or an `Int` or entirely different class `Resource`. I want to support these different type classes by adding extensions. At least thats what I thought the right approach would be, but

```
public protocol InstrumentProtocol : class  {
    associatedtype Item: AnyObject
    var item: Item? { get set }
    var identifier: String? { get }
}
public class AbstractBase : InstrumentProtocol {

    public var item: AnyObject?
    public var identifier: String?
    public init(_ i : AnyObject) {
        item = i
    }
    public func about() {
        print(self.item) // Any Object
    }
}

//// This is what I want to achieve, but it doesn't work
public extension InstrumentProtocol where Self.Item : Instrument {

    public func about() {
        print(self.item) //Should be of Instrument type
    }
}

 public extension InstrumentProtocol where Self.Item : String {

    public func about() {
        print(self.item) //Should be of String type
    }
}
```

The `item` property type is unknown to me. In this case, would would be the best possible approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class PropertyBase { }
class PropA : PropertyBase {}
class PropB : PropertyBase {}

protocol ControllerBaseType {
  associatedtype T: PropertyBase    
  var prop : T? { get set }
}

class ControllerA : ControllerBaseType {
  var prop: PropA?
}
class ControllerB : ControllerBaseType {
  var prop: PropB?
}
```

`ControllerBaseType` is abstract as you want and you have the specific implementation of `prop` in each subclass

**EDIT:**
According to @Honey comment, I simplified the code by removing type aliases from subclasses

**EDIT2:**
If you really need `ControllerBase` as a class you can do this that way:

```
class ControllerBase<T: PropertyBase> {
  var prop : T?
}

class PropertyBase { }
class PropA : PropertyBase {}
class PropB : PropertyBase {}

class ControllerA : ControllerBase<PropA> {}
class ControllerB : ControllerBase<PropB> {}
```

Comment: FWIW You can also conform _implicitly_. ie remove the `  typealias T = PropA` &   line. since the the `var prop: PropA?` will be enough for the compiler to infer. Same for ControllerB...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The reason I wanted a `ControllerBase` `Class` and not a protocol is because I could use that as an ivar in another class.

`class New { var controller : ControllerBase? }`, where I could implicitly use any of the `Controller` classes. 

Im confused.

Comment: Hmmm if I understand you correctly you could do this with `protocol`. Everything is ok until you try to create an instance of `ControllerBaseType ` but you could have variable of type `ControllerBaseType `

Comment: @user134611 please check EDIT2

Comment: *Everything is ok until you `don't` try to create an instance of `ControllerBaseType`...

Comment: I accepted the answer, Seems right to use this approach, but I guess I couldn't explain my question well. I wanted to develop a class that can be extended to support properties of different types. `var prop: PropA?` or `var prop: PropB?`.